# how can i take output individually from map type of data using for_each for vnet_id in azure in terraform instead of all vnet_id in single output

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

hello i am facing an issue while taking output form vnet i am able to take the output from map type  of data but its taking all vnet_id in one output in this case i am not able to call one vnet_id from this list of vnet_id in single output in remotestate
here i am taking output from map type of data no

```
 output "vnet_id" {
 value = tomap({
 for k, s in azurerm_virtual_network.vnet : k => s.id
  })
 }
```

this the out put i want these vnet_id individually as a output not all at once is it possible
that i can call vnet_id one by one in remotestate
here i am creating vnets 3 vnets using for_each

```
  # module.vnet.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet["dev-c2c"] will be created
 
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    + address_space       = [
      + "10.89.32.0/21",
        ]
    + dns_servers         = (known after apply)
    + guid                = (known after apply)
    + id                  = (known after apply)
    + location            = "eastus"
    + name                = "tfs-vnet-dev-c2c-eu-aiva"
    + resource_group_name = "tfs-rg-dev-eu-dev"
    + subnet              = (known after apply)
    + tags                = {
     + "environment" = "tfs"
     + "owner"       = "g7"
         }
        }
 
  # module.vnet.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet["dev-cde"] will be created
 
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    + address_space       = [
      + "10.89.24.0/21",
        ]
    + dns_servers         = (known after apply)
    + guid                = (known after apply)
    + id                  = (known after apply)
    + location            = "eastus"
    + name                = "tfs-vnet-dev-cde-eu-aiva"
    + resource_group_name = "tfs-rg-dev-eu-dev"
    + subnet              = (known after apply)
    + tags                = {
      + "environment" = "tfs"
      + "owner"       = "g7"
        }
       }

  # module.vnet.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet\["dev-oos"\] will be created
 
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    + address_space       = [
      + "10.89.40.0/21",
        ]
    + dns_servers         = (known after apply)
    + guid                = (known after apply)
    + id                  = (known after apply)
    + location            = "eastus"
    + name                = "tfs-vnet-dev-oos-eu-aiva"
    + resource_group_name = "tfs-rg-dev-eu-dev"
    + subnet              = (known after apply)
    + tags                = {
      + "environment" = "tfs"
      + "owner"       = "g7"
        }
       }
 
  Plan: 49 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
 
  Changes to Outputs:
 
  + vnet_id = {
    + "dev-c2c" = (known after apply)
    + "dev-cde" = (known after apply)
    + "dev-oos" = (known after apply)
      }
 
 i want output individually not in single list so can call one by one terraform remotestate'
```

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. What exactly is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: could you please share what exactly you want, if you want single vnet_id output then not sure why are you using tomap function to make a map object, write three outputs instead. May be clarify your issue with more details and an error message.